# Haskell: Flipping a curried dollar operator

Tags: haskell

Say I define this function:

```
f = ($ 5)
```

Then I can apply it:

```
> f (\x -> x ^ 2)
25
```

Its type is:

```
:t f
f :: (Integer -> b) -> b
```

Which makes sense, it gets a function as an argument, and returns this function applied on the `Integer` `5`.

Now I define this function:

```
g = flip f
```

I would expect this to not make sense, because `f` is a function of a single argument.

But, checking its type:

```
:t g
g :: b -> (Integer -> b -> c) -> c
```

So now `g` is a function of 2 arguments!

Applying it on some values:

```
> g [2, 4, 6] (\x y -> x:y)
[5,2,4,6]
```

What is going on here? What does `flip ($ 5)` really mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Follow the types:

```
($ 5) :: (Int -> a) -> a
flip  :: (x -> y -> z) -> y -> x -> z
```

But since `->` is right associative, the type `x -> y -> z` is equivalent to `x -> (y -> z)`, so

```
flip  :: (x         -> (y -> z)) -> y -> x -> z
($ 5) :: (Int -> a) -> a
```

So `x ~ (Int -> a)` and `(y -> z) ~ a`, so substituting back in:

```
($ 5) :: (Int -> (y -> z)) -> (y -> z)
```

And simplified

```
($ 5) :: (Int -> y -> z) -> y -> z
```

So

```
flip ($ 5) :: y -> (Int -> y -> z) -> z
```

Which is equivalent to the type you're seeing (although I used `Int` instead of `Integer` to save typing).

What this is saying is that the type of `($ 5)` gets specialized when passed to `flip` such that it takes a function of 2 arguments.  It is perfectly valid to have something like `($ 5) const`, where `const :: a -> b -> a` and `($ 5) const :: b -> Int`.  All `($ 5)` is doing is applying `5` as *an* argument to a function, not necessarily *the* argument for a function.  This is an example of partial application, where not all of the arguments are supplied to a function.  That's why you can do things like `map (subtract 1) [1, 2, 3]`.

An example of how to use `flip ($ 5)` is:

```
> flip ($ 5) 2 (**)
25.0
> flip ($ 5) 1 (-)
4.0
> let f x y = (x, y)
> flip ($ 5) 1 f
(5, 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

The confusion arises from the loose concept of "number of arguments" for polymorphic functions. For instance, it is tempting to say that

```
f :: (Integer -> b) -> b
```

has one argument (a function). Yet, a more precise statement would be that `f` is a function with *at least* one argument. This is because the type variable `b` can be substituted with any type, thanks to polymorphism, giving rise to e.g.

```
f :: (Integer -> String) -> String
f :: (Integer -> Double) -> Double
...
```

which are indeed functions with one argument, but *also* to, e.g.

```
f :: (Integer -> (String -> Double)) -> (String -> Double)
```

where `b` has been replaced with a functional type `String -> Double`. This substitution makes a second argument "appear" in an apparently magic way: `f` can take a first argument (a binary function `Integer -> String -> Double`), and then a second one (a `String`), before returning a `Double`.

Note that this phenomenon always appears when a polymorphic type ends with `... -> b` for some type variable `b`.

Let me conclude with a trivia: how "many" arguments has the identity function `id`? Well, intuitively I would say *one*, but let me check ...

```
> id (+) 3 4
7
> id id id id id (+) 3 4
7
```

... and perhaps *many* is a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

the function `flip` flips the order of the arguments, so all of these are equal:

```
f (\x y -> x:y) [2, 4, 6]
```

> [5,2,4,6]

```
flip f  [2, 4, 6] (\x y -> x:y)
```

> [5,2,4,6]

```
g [2, 4, 6] (\x y -> x:y)
```

> [5,2,4,6]